# Regular expression for 10digit phonenumber in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to write a Regular expression to match a 10 digit number without any other characters.
eg. 2345678901

the first digit should be between 2-9 
while rest 9 digits can be any

I have tried writing different Regular expressions but none worked.

NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

```
//^([0-9]+)?(([0-9]{9})?)?$     (([2-9]{1})?)?(([0-9]{8,9})?)?
NSString *expression = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^(([2-9]{1})?)?(([0-9]{8,9})?)?$"];

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:nil];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
if (numberOfMatches == 0) {
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

A very straightforward regex to match what you need is

```
^[2-9][0-9]{9}$
```

It matches the first digit in the 2..9 range, and the other nine digits in the 0..9 range, ten digits in total.

Note that this expression is suitable for validating the entire string, not a partial one. You cannot use it in `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to validate the digits as they become available.

It's not a good idea to validate the format of the input as it's being entered anyway, because users may choose to enter the phone's digits in any order by moving the cursor to the right position before they type. Instead, you should set the `keyboardType` property of your `UITextField` to `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad`, and let users type as many digits as they want. Don't limit their input until they tell you that they are done: they may want to paste data from, say, a notepad, and then erase the separators, or enter a few extra digits at the end before deleting a section at the front of the input.

Instead, you should use the above expression in the `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` method. When regex matches, return `YES`; otherwise, return `NO`, and give users some visual feedback to indicate that the number needs to be changed. Read the discussion section of the `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` method in `UITextFieldDelegate` documentation.

Comment: I had earlier tried with the same regular expression, but simulator doesnt even let me enter any digit.

Comment: @user2229791 I did not realize that you are trying to use the expression for partial validation. Take a look at the edit.